# Let $G$ be a group and $x,y\in G$. Suppose $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Is it possible to rewrite $[x^{n+1},y^{m+1}]$ as a conjugate of $[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $x,y\in G$. Suppose $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Is it possible to rewrite $[x^{n+1},y^{m+1}]$ as a conjugate of $[x,y]$? I am looking for commutator identities for when we are dealing with powers of elements.

Answer (score 6):

Without further conditions in general the answer would be no, since if for example the order of $\;x\;$ is $\;n+1\;$ or the order of $\;y\;$ is $\;m+1\;$ , then $\;[x^{n+1},y^{m+1}]=1\;$ , and $\;[x,y]=1\iff xy=yx\;$ , and from  here you can build lots of counter examples, say:

$$x=(123),\,y=(1234)\in S_4\;,\;\;n=2, y=3\implies[x^{2+1},y^{3+1}]=[1,1]=1$$

whereas

$$[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=(132)(1432)(123)(1234)=(1423)(1342)=(243)$$

Answer (score 1):

Don Antonio has already given counterexamples.

But this is also not true in free groups. In a free group, two elements are conjugate if and only if the reduced words that represent them are cyclic conjugates (sometimes called cylci shifts) of each other. For example $xyx^{-1}yy$ is conjugate to $x^{-1}yyxy$.

But it is easy to see that in the free group freely generated by $x$ and $y$,   $[x^m,y^n]$ is a cyclic conjugate of $[x^j,y^k]$ if and only if $m=j$ and $n=k$.